# Haskell Create key value map

Tags: haskell

I have to be kind of dumb, but watching all blogs and documentation https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.4.2.0/docs/Data-Map.html

I cannot figure how to create a simple Map collection with a simple key -> value.

Sorry I´m very newby.

Comment: This might be useful for you: https://haskell-containers.readthedocs.io/en/latest/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure you have `containers` package installed via cabal or stack. I am assuming you want to use the latest version of the [package (0.5.11.0)](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.11.0/docs/Data-Map-Strict.html). The link on hackage that you posted points to very old version of the package.

Then import the `Data.Map`

```
import qualified Data.Map.Strict as Map
import Data.Map (Map())
```

Use `fromList` function to create a map

```
-- map with ints as keys and strings as values
myMap :: Map Int String
myMap = Map.fromList [(5,"a"), (3,"b"), (5, "c")]
```

If you want to cut the boilerplate, you can use `OverloadedLists` extension.

```
-- put extensions at the top of your file
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedLists #-}

import qualified Data.Map.Strict as Map
import Data.Map (Map())

-- map with ints as keys and strings as values
myMap :: Map Int String
myMap = [(5,"a"), (3,"b"), (5, "c")]
```

Comment: I just saw the fromList operator, but I was wondering if it was a simple way without have to create a list. Still is what I´m doing already, thanks a lot for the answer

Comment: Unfortunately, the syntax is little bit verbose. You can make it a little bit less verbose by enabling `OverloadedLists` extension. You can then omit calling fromList. I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: myMap = [(5,"a"), (3,"b"), (5, "c")]
 how is possible that this is not getting conflict with a List of tuple of (Int, String) ??!

Comment: Because myMap is explicitly typed as Map Int String. If the type can be derived from context (from usage), it can be omitted.

Answer (score 2):

you should look for functions with signature like `a -> b -> ... -> Map k v`, where none of a,b... (the input parameters) is a Map. From Data.Map such are `empty`, which creates empty map, `singleton`, which creates map with one element, and all flavours of `from*List*`

Comment: I found Singleton which I think is the same than a fromList with one element. But well now is pretty clear the API. Thanks